# Unable to do immutable managed update in single instance environment in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, elastic-beanstalk

I am unable to successfully execute immutable managed update in single instance environment. Process always timeouts with this error as shown in events page:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-blabla-immutable-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

There is not more information about what went wrong. EB environment is in custom VPC. I am not sure what other information to provide, for you to help me.

Is there an option to see logs about what went wrong?

Thank you